# Can someone explain this Picasso Adapter for GridView?

Tags: android, gridview, adapter

I'm kinda new in android development also in Stackoverflow (sorry because this question is kinda not following the rules) so, i want to ask something about this [tutorial](https://futurestud.io/blog/picasso-adapter-use-for-listview-gridview-etc)

EDIT : i just figure it myself and i got an error in "listview.setAdapter"

```
public class UsageExampleAdapter extends AppCompatActivity {
public static String[] eatFoodyImages = {
        "http://i.imgur.com/rFLNqWI.jpg",
        "http://i.imgur.com/C9pBVt7.jpg",
        "http://i.imgur.com/rT5vXE1.jpg",
        "http://i.imgur.com/aIy5R2k.jpg",
        "http://i.imgur.com/MoJs9pT.jpg",
        "http://i.imgur.com/S963yEM.jpg",
        "http://i.imgur.com/rLR2cyc.jpg",
        "http://i.imgur.com/SEPdUIx.jpg",
        "http://i.imgur.com/aC9OjaM.jpg",
        "http://i.imgur.com/76Jfv9b.jpg",
        "http://i.imgur.com/fUX7EIB.jpg",
        "http://i.imgur.com/syELajx.jpg",
        "http://i.imgur.com/COzBnru.jpg",
        "http://i.imgur.com/Z3QjilA.jpg",
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_usage_example_adapter);

    listView.setAdapter(new ImageListAdapter(UsageExampleAdapter.this, eatFoodyImages));
}
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify a little more what you are looking for?  Are you asking where to put that xml file?

Comment: what exactly you want??

Answer (score 0):

When you make an android application basic folders are created by IDE.As per android directory structure xml file which represent layout of application should be located in res->layout folder. As per my suggestion it is better to get overview of android from rather than jump into project.http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html

Comment: thanks for the answers.
i just edited the questions.

Comment: You need to initialize your listview like listview =(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);